# How to create a model that simply returns y value based on closest x and y values?

Tags: r, model

I have a set of data for `x` (`x1`) and `y` (`y1`). I need to get a new set of data with defined `x` (`x2`) values (so I need to find corresponding `y` values (`y2`)). For every `x2` I want the model to find two x1 points between which `x2` is, and then connect them with a straight line and find the corresponding `y2`.

Basically I want to build a plot through x1 and y1 points, where they are connceted with straight lines and then do a procedure analogous to extracting values from this plot.

Comment: Is difficult to deduce what exactly you're after. Please include a minimal reproducible example, including sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: If I understand right... for a given `x2`, you want to find the 2 points, not necessarily _closest_ to `x2`, but whose _line connecting them_ is closest to `x2`?

Comment: I think you are looking for the `approx` function. Something like `approx(x = x1, y = y1, xout = x2, method = "linear")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively,

```
f = approxfun(x,y)
```

Should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do is create a linear model that predicts Y for a given X based on the data you already have.

This is very straightforward in R, assuming your main dataframe is called df1 and the second one is called df2, this will output 'y2' predictions for 'x2':

```
fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = df1)
new <- data.frame(x = df2$x)
predict(fit, new)
```

If you want to plot the line on a chart you could easily do that separately in ggplot:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x, y) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method='lm')
```